# How do I set the list icon?

Tags: microsoft-to-do

[image: day in focus]

Microsoft To-Do's advertising has little pictogram icons next to each list. (It's actually the only part I liked over Wunderlist...) But I have clicked everywhere and can't seem to customize beyond each list's color theme. Am I missing something?